# Auto-formatting code on Pycharm running on Ubuntu distros

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

I have been using Pycharm on Ubuntu for some time for development, and something bother me a lot. Every time I paste some code I have to press **Ctrl + Alt + Shift + L** to format code and indentations. I don't have to do this on Windows or Fedora, where this is done automatically.

I talking about this:

Before: 
[image]

After:
[image]

This one is just and example, but that is the concept.

How can I turn on this automatic formatting on paste?

Comment: Do you have "Reformat on paste" option enabled in "Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Smart Keys" and "Smart indent pasted lines" for Python submenu?

Comment: @y.bedrov this solves! for some reason this option is disabled by default on ubuntu distros. And also I never saw someone mention this option. Thank you very much!